# Using mmap to copy data from memory to file

Tags: c, optimization, mmap

My question is simple, i would like to know how can I use mmap to copy a binary data from memory to a file (if it is possible of course), actualy I'm trying to optimize my program, I was using fwrite but it takes a lot of time, and I wounder if i can use mmap for this.

```
int * data = malloc(sizeof(int) * 100000000000);
// do something to data
//copy this data to a file
```

thanks

Comment: Nope. `int *data = mmap(NULL, sizeof(int) * HUGE, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);` then modify `data` and it will be persisted to file.

Comment: i was trying what you said but I get a seg fault : `int fd = open (argv[1], O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC);
 int * data = mmap(0, sizeof(int) * 10000, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
 data[0] = 1;`

Comment: The file has to be big enough to contain the data. `mmap` does not grow the file, so when you hit an address which doesn't correspond to the the file you get a segfault. Anyway, it's unlikely that `mmap` will be faster than fwrite provided you are fwriting a reasonable buffer size which is aligned to actual file buffers.

Comment: I'm trying to copy 1G of data, fwrite takes 24 sec (Actualy its fclose() who takes all this time !) so I'm looking for another idea

Comment: Even if you would succeed, the speed would not increase. The speed only depends on the bandwidth of the disk-I/O, which is the same for both scenarios.